# Copy Worksheets break links

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below 2 subs in VBA which perform 2 different but similar tasks. One allows you to selects sheets from a Workbook using a checkbox popup and then copies these sheets into a new blank Workbook. The other allows you to manually populate a list of names of the sheets you want to copy (i.e. setup a "batch" of sorts) on a sheet and then copy all the sheets across into a new blank Workbook in a similar fashion to the first.

The problem I am having is - with the first sub I am able to break links after copying into the new Workbook, but with the second sub I am not able to break links. I think it has to do with a number of defined names within the original Workbook, as if you "Move or Copy/Create a Copy" manually, you are able to break the links.

Is there any code I can add to the below (onto both subs if possible) which will automatically break all links in the new Workbook to the old one? Or at least, is it possible to amend the second sub so that it copies across in a similar fashion to the first one which will then allow me to break links manually?

```
Sub CopySelectedSheets()

'1. Declare variables
Dim I As Integer
Dim SheetCount As Integer
Dim TopPos As Integer
Dim lngCheckBoxes As Long, y As Long
Dim intTopPos As Integer, intSheetCount As Integer
Dim intHor As Integer       
Dim intWidth As Integer     
Dim intLBLeft As Integer, intLBTop As Integer, intLBHeight As Integer
Dim Printdlg As DialogSheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet, wsStartSheet As Worksheet
Dim CB As CheckBox
Dim firstSelected As Boolean

'    Dim wb As Workbook
'    Dim wbNew As Workbook
'    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
'    Workbooks.Add ' Open a new workbook
'    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'2. Check for protected workbook
If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure Then
    MsgBox "Workbook is protected.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

'3. Add a temporary dialog sheet
Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
Set wsStartSheet = ActiveSheet
Set Printdlg = ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets.Add

SheetCount = 0

'4. Add the checkboxes
TopPos = 40
For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
    'Skip empty sheets and hidden sheets
    If Application.CountA(CurrentSheet.Cells) <> 0 And _
        CurrentSheet.Visible Then
        SheetCount = SheetCount + 1
        Printdlg.CheckBoxes.Add 78, TopPos, 150, 16.5
            Printdlg.CheckBoxes(SheetCount).Text = _
                CurrentSheet.Name
        TopPos = TopPos + 13
    End If
Next I

'6. Move the OK and Cancel buttons
Printdlg.Buttons.Left = 240

'7. Set dialog height, width, and caption
With Printdlg.DialogFrame
    .Height = Application.Max _
        (68, Printdlg.DialogFrame.Top + TopPos - 34)
    .Width = 230
    .Caption = "Select sheets to generate"

End With

'Change tab order of OK and Cancel buttons
'so the 1st option button will have the focus
Printdlg.Buttons("Button 2").BringToFront
Printdlg.Buttons("Button 3").BringToFront

'9. Display the dialog box
CurrentSheet.Activate
wsStartSheet.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
If SheetCount <> 0 Then


        If Printdlg.Show Then
                For Each CB In Printdlg.CheckBoxes

                    If CB.Value = xlOn Then
                        If firstSelected Then
                            Worksheets(CB.Caption).Select Replace:=False
                    Else
                        Worksheets(CB.Caption).Select
                        firstSelected = True
                    End If

                    'For y = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                        'If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber _
                        '(InStr(1, "ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(y)", "Contents")) = True Then
                            'CB.y = xlOn
                        'End If
                    End If

                Next


                ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy

        Else
            MsgBox "No worksheets selected"


        End If

End If

'   Delete temporary dialog sheet (without a warning)
''    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
''    Printdlg.Delete

'   Reactivate original sheet
''    CurrentSheet.Activate
''    wsStartSheet.Activate

'10.Delete temporary dialog sheet (without a warning)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Printdlg.Delete

'11.Reactivate original sheet
CurrentSheet.Activate
wsStartSheet.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub CopySpecificSheets()

'1. Declare Variables
Dim myArray() As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim OldBook As String
Dim newBook As String
Dim a As Long

'2. Set Range of Lookup
Set myRange = Sheets("Report Batch").Range("A2:A40")

OldBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'3. Generate Array of Sheet Names removing Blanks
For Each Cell In myRange
If Not Cell = "" Then
    a = a + 1
    ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To a)
    myArray(a) = Cell
End If
Next

'4. Copy Array of Sheets to new Workbook
For a = 1 To UBound(myArray)
If a = 1 Then
    Sheets(myArray(a)).Copy
    newBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(OldBook).Activate
Else
    Sheets(myArray(a)).Copy After:=Workbooks(newBook).Sheets(a - 1)
    Workbooks(OldBook).Activate
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub CopySpecificSheets()

    '1. Declare Variables
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim arrSheets() As String
    Dim lSheetCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    '2. Initialize variables
    Set rngData = Sheets("Report Batch").Range("A2:A40")
    arrData = rngData.Value
    lSheetCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngData)
    ReDim arrSheets(lSheetCount - 1)


    '3. Fill the array with non blank sheet names
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then
            arrSheets(j) = arrData(i, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
        ' early break if we have all the sheets
        If j = lSheetCount Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    '4. Copy the sheets in one step
    Sheets(arrSheets).Copy

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I've tested and seems to work perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested, but I think if you add in a subroutine to your source workbook VBA code like this:

```
Sub BreakLinks(ByRef wb As Workbook)

        Dim Links As Variant
        Dim i As Long

        On Error Resume Next
        Links = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not IsEmpty(Links) Then
                For i = 1 To UBound(Links)
                        wb.BreakLink Name:=Links(i), _
                                Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
                Next i
        End If

End Sub
```

And then call it after you copy the sheets to the new workbook

```
Call BreakLinks(newBook)
```

That should achieve the desired effect of severing those links. Just be sure the links are broken to any sort of `Save` or `SaveAs` operation so that the broken links are maintained.

Comment: I wonder if you need to loop backwards stop as not to skip links?

Comment: Looping forward may skip links? Do you know why that would be? I always forget about looking backwards in VBA I think I've only used it once or twice in my career. Interesting concern.

Comment: It would be similar to the problem when deleting rows.You're looping through an incrementer while deleting the things it increments.